# Не работает aspect-ratio с flex-direction: column;

Tags: html, css, flexbox

не могу понять почему не срабатывает свойство aspect-ratio с flex-direction: column;? Без него все работает хорошо.
Пример кода:

```css
.a {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.b {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 5 / 1;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2022-06/1655370600_27-phonoteka-org-p-kachestvennie-oboi-na-rabochii-stol-28.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: с какого браузера смотрите?

Comment: Google Chrome, проверил в Firefox все работает нормально.